# Count of rows for 2 days

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My data is in below format:

```
employee    order id   date   
a           123         01/06/2013
b           124         02/06/2013 
a           125         02/06/2013 
a           129         02/06/2013
```

I need the data in below format:

```
employee   day 1    day 2
a           1        2
b           0        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      dtStart DATETIME
    , employees CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (employees, dtStart) VALUES('a','01/06/2013')
INSERT INTO @temp (employees, dtStart) VALUES('a','01/06/2013')
INSERT INTO @temp (employees, dtStart) VALUES('b','02/06/2013')

SELECT 
       employees
     , day1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DAY(dtStart) = 1 THEN 1 END)
     , day2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DAY(dtStart) = 2 THEN 1 END) 
FROM @temp
--WHERE dtStart BETWEEN '01/06/2013' AND '30/06/2013'
GROUP BY employees
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work (depending on whether you have a fixed amount of days or not):

```
select employee,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '01/06/2013' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as day1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '02/06/2013' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as day2
from table
group by employee
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i want count of records for perticular period. this period ranges from every week of current month and every month of year

Comment: @user2527359 You could try CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '01/06/2013' AND '02/06/2013' (or other combinations of dates)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct employees, 
SUM(CASE WHEN dtStart = '01/06/2013' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as day1,
SUM(CASE WHEN dtStart = '02/06/2013' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as day2 
from yourTable
group by dtStart,employees
```

[see your demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63f22/6)

Comment: it seems you posted around the same time as I did with nearly identical code. I was wondering though, any specific reason why you group on dtStart and use distinct?